# Patent application file on arxiv

Tags: publications, copyright, patents

Is it wise to upload the published patent application file on arxiv?
what will be the consequences of copy right?

Comment: Won't the patent application be published by the patent office, and become publicly accessible anyway? Is there a difference between that publication and the file you intend to upload to arXiv?

Comment: Yes it will be available to public but I want to increase the readership base.

Comment: I'm not sure if your typical arXiv reader would appreciate reading a patent application, which uses a different style and language and has a different purpose from an academic paper. Is there an academic paper/abstract associated with the patent application? If so, perhaps that would be a better candidate for arXiv? You can then cite your patent application in that paper.

Comment: Doesn't publishing it make it prior art that then stops you from obtaining a patent?

Comment: Why are you interested in many people reading a patent application? Is this a form of marketing?

Answer (score 7):

You can't upload your patent application materials to arXiv, because they simply don't accept that kind of submission.

https://arxiv.org/help/moderation:

> arXiv accepts only submissions in the form of an article that would be refereeable by a conventional publication venue.

Your file isn't an article, and "conventional publication venues" (journals, conference proceedings, etc) don't publish or referee patent applications.    If you submit it, it will probably be rejected in the moderation process.

Whether it would be legally advisable to make your file publicly available some other way, or to write and publish an article about your invention, and how any of this might affect the validity of your patent, are questions that you need to ask your patent attorney.  It would be very unwise to rely on the advice of random Internet strangers for something like that.